# Smooth submanifold of a complex manifold with invariant tangent space under multiplication by $i$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ be a complex manifold, $N$ is a smooth immersed submanifold of $M$. If $T_p M$ is invariant under the multiplication by $i$ for any $p\in M$, then can we conclude that $N$ is a complex immersed submanifold of $M$?

Since $C^1$ property somehow means analytic property in complex setting, can we drop the assumption to that $N$ is merely a $C^1$ submanifold?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f : N \to M$ denote the immersion.
Since $f_*TN$ is invariant under $I$ where $I$ is the underlying almost complex structure of $M$, it induces an almost complex structure $I'$ on $N$.
Applying Newlander-Nirenberg theorem, we see that since
$I$ is integrable, $I'$ is also integrable.
Thus $I'$ is a complex structure on $N$, and
$f: (N,I') \to (M,I)$
is holomorphic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can we get a similar result when $f$ is merely a $C^r (r\ge1)$  immersion ?

Comment: @Chickenfeed: yes. In any holomorphic coordinates in which the immersed image is local the graph of some coordinates as $C^1$ functions of others, the image (of any open subset on which $f$ is an embedding) is a $C^1$ solution of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, so has image a complex submanifold to which $f$ immerses, so the complex structure pulls back and so on.

Comment: @Ben McKay：Thank you for the answer. But how to gurantee that there is such a holomorphic coordinate in which  the immersed image is local the graph of some coordinates as $C1$ functions of others.  Did you use the invariant property of the tangent space? Since $N$ can be odd dimentional without this condition.

Comment: @Chickenfeed: Since the tangent space is $I$-invariant, it is a complex linear subspace. Pick one point $n_0\in N$. Take holomorphic local coordinates $z^{\mu},w^{\nu}$ so that $f_*T_{n_0} N$ is the complex linear subspace $w=0$ at the origin of coordinates. So at $n_0$, the real and imaginary parts of the various $dz^{\mu}$ are linearly independent, and so also nearby. So we can replace $n_0$ with a neighborhood on which the real and imaginary parts of $z$ are local coordinates on $N$. Replace $N$ by a small neighborhood of $n_0$ on which they are global coordinates.

Comment: (2) Now on $N$, $w$ is a $C^1$ function of $z$. But each tangent space is complex linear, so $dw$ is a complex linear function of $dz$, i.e. the Cauchy--Riemann equations are satisfied.